# Statistical method to map a set of values to another

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

I am completely newbie to stats. And I want to know which statistical method would be applicable for following scenario.

I have a bunch of sentences extracted from a text document. Each sentence has a specific integer value say X which ranges from 1-5. Each sentence also have another logarithmic value Y which can be positive or negative. There is not relation (direct or inverse proportion) between X and Y. I would like to decide in a mapping of each Y value to a specific X value using those bunch of statements.

e.g. Lets say I have 12 sentences with X and Y values as follows:

```
                 X    |    Y

Sentence 1  :    1    |  0.00
Sentence 2  :    1    |  1.05
Sentence 3  :    2    |  0.00
Sentence 4  :    3    |  12.0
Sentence 5  :    5    |  2.0
Sentence 6  :    4    |  -1.0
Sentence 7  :    5    |  -9.0
Sentence 8  :    2    |  0.0
Sentence 9  :    3    |  15.0
Sentence 10 :    1    |  0.0
```

Then I want to decide what ranges of Y would fit in for 1,2,3,4,5 values of X.

I guess some form of regression would be right option here. But I am not sure the exact method will be applicable here.